# Find records in MongoDB that does NOT match a contition

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need to pass a condition to `find` method. But with compare operator `!=`. Is it possible in MongoDB? I see in [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/shell/query/) operators like `AND`, `OR`, `&lt`, `&gt`, but the negate operator. Do you have any idea how to fetch all the record, that `recordType` is not equal `Message`?

```
collection.find({'recordType' : 'Message'}).toArray(function(err, results) {
    // <-- need NOT EQUAL OPERATOR
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$ne` is the solution.

> Syntax: `{field: {$ne: value} }`
>
> `$ne` selects the documents where the value of the field is `not equal (i.e. !=)` to the specified value. This includes documents that do not contain the field.

```
collection.find({'recordType' : {'$ne' : 'Message'}}).toArray(function(err, results) 
{
    console.log(results);
});
```

Refer [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/) to know how to use it.

Comment: `$ne`, not `'$ne'`

Comment: @Clijsters it will work with'$ne' as well.

Comment: Interesting. Checked [Book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028031.do), which says you're right but [online manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query-comparison/) only provides operators without surrounding marks. Anything known about this with older versions or doesn't it matter?

Comment: You can try running the query with quote and without quote. It will give same result only. I never did any kind of research about this, so I have no idea is there any difference in using with and without `quotes`. If anybody knows I will be glad to know.